# Understanding Fixed-point fractional part

Tags: c, fixed-point

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Fixed-point numbers. So far so good. The only thing that got me confused is the 'fractional' part of the number.

My understanding of Fixed-point numbers is that it splits the binary number according to the scale (which in this case is equal to eight bits). The left side would be the integer part, and the fraction is to the right.
`XXX.Y` where `XXX` are the three bytes for the integer/whole part, and `Y` is one byte for the fractional part (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Let's take the following macros:

```
#define FIX_SCALE 8
#define FIX_FRACTION_MASK ((1 << FIX_SCALE) - 1)
#define FIX_WHOLE_MASK ~FIX_FRACTION_MASK
#define FIX_FROM_FLOAT(X) ((X) * (1 << FIX_SCALE))
#define FIX_TO_FLOAT(X) ((float)(X) / (1 << FIX_SCALE))
#define FIX_TO_INT(X) ((X) >> FIX_SCALE)
#define FIX_FROM_INT(X) ((X) << FIX_SCALE)
#define FIX_FRACTION(X) ((X) & FIX_FRACTION_MASK)
#define FIX_WHOLE(X) ((X) & FIX_WHOLE_MASK)
```

Consider the following example:

```
int Fixed = FIX_FROM_FLOAT(2.5f);
```

The resulting integer value is `640`, `0x280` in hex and `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 1000 0000` in binary.

Let's take the first two bytes: `0000 0010 1000 0000`

I understand where the `0000 0010` comes from, it's the integer part (`2`). But what I don't get is the `1000 0000` which is the fractional part. I just don't see how that relates to the number 5 (which is 0101 in binary). I would have expected something like `0101 0000` or `0000 0101` -- Clearly I'm misunderstanding a fundamental concept here.

If I write:

```
int Fraction = FIX_FRACTION(Fixed);
```

I would get `128` (`0x80` in hex. Makes sense cause it masked out the integer part which is `2`). The first time I wrote that I expected to get a `5` back.

I do get `0.5` if I write:

```
float Fraction = FIX_TO_FLOAT(FIX_FRACTION(Fixed));
```

Could somebody clear this confusion for me? Why did the fraction number `0000 1000` not have any `101` in it? Why did we have to do the `FIX_TO_FLOAT` on `FIX_FRACTION` to get the right fraction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing number patterns in decimal and binary representation does not work.
Lets forget about fixed point numbers for a moment and have a look at the binary representations of 5 and 50:

```
 5: 0000'0101
50: 0011'0010
```

As you can see, the binary pattern of a decimal 5 cannot be found in the binary representation of decimal 50 either.

Now to understand why decimal 0.5 is ..00'1000'0000 in Q23.8 binary, you need to follow the binary to decimal conversion rule:

Replace every 1 with 2^position and add up the numbers

```
position:      7 6 5 4  3 2 1 0  -1-2-3-4 -5-6-7-8
binary number: 0 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 . 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
```

2^1 + 2^-1 = 2 + 0.5 = 2.5

Answer (score 3):

Integer numbers represent different powers of 10:

[image: Integer columns decimal representation] ([source](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/elementary_math/rounding_numbers_and_place_value/place_value))

So 10203 = 1×10000 + 0×1000 + 2×100 + 0×10 + 3×1

And decimals continue this pattern, representing the negative powers of 10:

[image: Fractional columns decimal representation]

So 0.10203 = 1/10 + 0/100 + 2/1000 + 0/10000 + 3/100000

The decimal number 2.5 has a "2" in the 2s column, and a "5" in the 1/10ths column, so the total is 2×1 + 5/10.

Binary fixed point works exactly the same way, except with powers of 2 instead of 10.  The integers part is the 1s column, the 2s column, the 4s column, the 8s column, etc. and the fractional part is the 1/2s column, 1/4ths column, 1/8ths column, etc.

So for example, if the number is in 4.4 format, where the first nibble is unsigned integer part and second nibble is fractional part, for the binary number 1010 1001, the integer part represents

1×8 + 0×4 + 1×2 + 0×1

The fractional part represents

1/2 + 0/4 + 0/8 + 1/16

So the decimal equivalent would be

1×8 + 0×4 + 1×2 + 0×1 + 1/2 + 0/4 + 0/8 + 1/16

= 10.5625

The signed version is similar:

[image: signed binary 4.4 representation] ([source](https://www.edn.com/design/programmable-logic/4014834/Rounding-Algorithms-101-Redux))

So in your binary format, where 2.5 is `0b0000 0010 1000 0000`, the first byte has 1 in the 2s column, a 0 in the 1s column, so it's

... + 0×4 + 1×2 + 0×1 + 1/2 + 0/4 + 0/8 + ...

Answer (score 0):

The binary values to the right of the . are 1/2 1/4 1/8 etc 
Hence 10.1 binary is 2.5

Comment: To expand on my answer- binary is a number system not an encoding.  It is base two instead of base ten. .5 d is 1/2 is 0.1b

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ".5 d is 1/2 is 0.1b"? Could you elaborate more perhaps?

Comment: sorry to be slow. binary numbers have binary weights (exponents) on both sides of the decimal point. 1/2 is equal to 0.1 in binary because the value of the first decimal place is 1/2. In decimal math the value to the right  of the decimal point is 1/10. 1/2 = 5/10 = 0.5 decimal